# Снять выбор с radio button(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, input

Есть 2 radio button в таблицы:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="oneBed" id="oneBed" value="1">
        <label for="oneBed">1 bed in room</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="twoBed" id="twoBed" value="2">
        <label for="twoBed">2 bed in room</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Нужно, чтобы при смене выбора check был снят с другого radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взаимоисключаемость радио-кнопок обусловлена одинаковым значением атрибута `name`.

```html
<table cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="bedCount" id="oneBed" value="1">
        <label for="oneBed">1 bed per room</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="bedCount" id="twoBed" value="2">
        <label for="twoBed">2 beds per room</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```